# Php GD not working for a simple test

Tags: php, apache, gd

Php GD sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't!

I'm using a simple test and still getting the error message.

Code in test.php :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$x = 50; 
$y = 100; 
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($x,$y);
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image); 
?>
```

Code in gdtest.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="test.php">
</body>
</html>
```

GD Support  is enabled, and im using GD Version bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

Can you help please?

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: And why you are using `test.php` in `<img src="test.php">`?

Comment: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: @Virb it's because I need to call the php file containing the image

Comment: Unable to reproduce your problem:- https://prnt.sc/j9t9y4   and https://prnt.sc/j9ta7x  and https://prnt.sc/j9tada

Comment: i see no error in code.

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks for the screen shots, I tried doing that too and still doesn't work :// I'm afraid that it's a problem of php librairies or whatever (I'm using PHP Version 5.6.31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one thing, check your `gd` library is installed or not with this:

```
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
}
else {
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
}
```

And Make sure there is nothing before `<?php` and remove `?>` at the end from your `test.php` file.

Comment: thank you sooooooo much :D it was because I had commented code before the php tag

Comment: @YosraMH: Glad to help. :D